# Buggy bouncing balls

Tags: processing, collision

I was making a colliding ball sketch in Processing, and I encountered a weird bug. Despite having a condition for bouncing off of the walls, **some balls get stuck to it**. I can't find the source of error here. Can someone help? I also realise that there maybe few (a lot) bad coding practices, but I apologise beforehand.

I am posting the codes below.

1) Main : https://pastebin.com/hv0H14gZ

```
particle[] elec = new particle[5];

boolean record = false;

void setup(){
  float x=0,y=0;
  int i,j;
  float diam = 100;

  size(800,400);

  //Initialising the particle objects
  for (int k = 0; k < elec.length; k++){
    x = random(width/10, width/1.2);
    y = random(height/10, height/1.2);
    elec[k] = new particle(x,y);
  }

  //Spawning at random places
  for ( i = 0; i < elec.length; i++){

   if (i!=0){

     for (  j = 0; j < elec.length; j ++){

       if (dist(x,y,elec[j].getX(),elec[j].getY()) <= diam){
         x = random(width/10, width/1.2);
         y = random(height/10, height/1.2);
         j = -1;
       }
     }
  }

    elec[i] = new particle(x,y,diam,4,4,2);


  }


}
void draw(){
  background(0);

  for (int i = 0; i < elec.length; i++){
    elec[i].update(elec);
    elec[i].move();
    elec[i].bounce();
    if(record){
      saveFrame("collide_#####.png");
      fill(255,0,0);
    } else {
      fill(0,255,0);
    }

    ellipse(width/1.01, height/1.01,5,5);
  }

}

void keyPressed(){
  if (key =='r' || key =='R'){
    record = !record;
  }
}
```

2) Classes : https://pastebin.com/Rt49sN9c

```
public class velocity{
  float delx, dely;

  //Constructor 1 
  public velocity(){}

  //Constructor 2
  public velocity(float delx, float dely){
    this.delx = delx;
    this.dely = dely;
  }

  //Mutators for xvelocity and y velocity
  public float getdelx(){
    return this.delx;
  }

  public float getdely(){
    return this.dely;
  }

  //Accessors for xvelocity and y velocity
  public void setdelx(float delx){
    this.delx = delx;
  }

  public void setdely(float dely){
    this.dely = dely;
  }

}






public class particle{

  private float xpos , ypos, delx , dely,size, decay, mass;
  color colour;

  //constructor 1
  public particle(float x, float y){
  this.xpos = x;
  this.ypos = y;
  }

  //constructor 2
  public particle(float xpos, float ypos, float size, float delx, float dely, float mass){
    this.xpos = xpos;
    this.ypos = ypos;
    this.size = size;
    this.delx = delx;
    this.dely = dely;
    this.mass = mass;

  }

  //Mutators for size, x velocity y velocity and velocity vector
  public void setsize(float size){
    this.size = size;
  }

  public void setDX(float delx){
    this.delx = delx;
  }

  public void setDY(float dely){
    this.dely = dely;
  }




  //Accessors for size, x position, y position, x velocity and y velocity

  public float getsize(){
    return this.size;
  }

  public float getX(){
    return this.xpos;
  }

  public float getY(){
    return this.ypos;
  }

  public float getDX(){
    return this.delx;
  }

  public float getDY(){
    return this.dely;
  }

  public float getmass(){
    return this.mass;
  }

  public velocity getvel(){

    velocity v = new velocity(this.getDX(), this.getDY());
    return v;
  }



  //Functionality. Moving around, Bouncing off of walls, and basic display updates
  public void move(){
    this.xpos += this.delx;
    this.ypos += this.dely;
  }

  public void bounce(){
    if((this.xpos - this.size/2.0) < 0 || (this.xpos + this.size/2.0) > width){
      this.setDX(this.getDX()*-1);
    }
    if((this.ypos - this.size/2.0) < 0 || (this.ypos + this.size/2.0) > height){
       this.setDY(this.getDY()*-1);
    }
  }

  public void update(particle[] elec){

    for(int i =0; i< elec.length; i++){

      if(this == elec[i]) continue;
      if(dist(this.getX(),this.getY(),elec[i].getX(),elec[i].getY()) - this.getsize() <0){
        collision(this, elec[i]);
        //println(dist(this.getX(),this.getY(),elec[i].getX(),elec[i].getY()) - this.getsize()/2);
      }
    }
    display();
  }

  public void display(){
    stroke(0);
    fill(119,240,153);   
    ellipse(this.xpos, this.ypos, this.size ,this.size);
  }
}



velocity rotate(velocity v, float angle){
  float x = v.getdelx()*cos(angle) - v.getdely()*sin(angle);
  float y = v.getdelx()*sin(angle) + v.getdely()*cos(angle);

  velocity vel = new velocity(x,y);
  return vel;
}



void collision(particle p1, particle p2){

  float xveldiff = p1.getDX()-p2.getDX();
  float yveldiff = p1.getDY()-p2.getDY();

  float xdist = p2.getX() - p1.getX();
  float ydist = p2.getY() - p1.getY();

  //Check for accidental overlaps of particles
  if(xveldiff*xdist + yveldiff*ydist > 0){

    float angle = -atan2(p2.getY() - p1.getY(), p2.getX() - p1.getY());

    float m1 = p1.getmass();
    float m2 = p2.getmass();

    velocity u1 = rotate(p1.getvel(),angle);
    velocity u2 = rotate(p2.getvel(),angle);

    velocity v1 = new velocity(u1.getdelx() * (m1 - m2) / (m1 + m2) + u2.getdelx() * 2 * m2 / (m1 + m2), u1.getdely());
    velocity v2 = new velocity(u2.getdelx() * (m1 - m2) / (m1 + m2) + u1.getdelx() * 2 * m2 / (m1 + m2), u2.getdely());

    velocity vf1 = rotate(v1, -angle);
    velocity vf2 = rotate(v2, -angle);

    p1.setDX(vf1.getdelx());
    p1.setDY(vf1.getdely());

    p2.setDX(vf2.getdelx());
    p2.setDY(vf2.getdely());
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice animation, the issue is cased by the method `bounce` of class `particle`:

When the "ball" doesn't leave the wall in one step, then it sticks.
Note, if e.g the condition `(this.xpos - this.size/2.0) < 0` is fulfilled twice, the the direction is inverted twice (`this.getDX()*-1`). This causes that the ball bounce into the wall continuously and leads to a trembling movement along the wall.

> ```
>  public void bounce(){
>
>      if((this.xpos - this.size/2.0) < 0 || (this.xpos + this.size/2.0) > width){
>          this.setDX(this.getDX()*-1);
>      }
>      if((this.ypos - this.size/2.0) < 0 || (this.ypos + this.size/2.0) > height){
>          this.setDY(this.getDY()*-1);
>      }
>  }
> ```

You have to ensure, the the direction (`delx`, `dely`) always points away from the wall, if the ball is to near to it:

```java
public void bounce(){

    if( this.xpos - this.size/2.0 < 0 ) {
        this.setDX( Math.abs(this.getDX()) );
    } else if( this.xpos + this.size/2.0 > width ) {
        this.setDX( -Math.abs(this.getDX()) );
    }

    if( this.ypos - this.size/2.0 < 0 ) {
        this.setDY( Math.abs(this.getDY()) );
    } else if( this.ypos + this.size/2.0 > height ) {
        this.setDY( -Math.abs(this.getDY()) );
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I realised it was the bounce method that was messing things up but couldn't figure out how. Thank you so much!